# Removing Aspects

Tags: reus

I placed a couple Fruit Aspects onto some Strawberries for extra Food. Now that I don't need it anymore, I want to place some other Aspects to I can upgrade it. Is there a way to remove already placed Aspects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't remove aspects once they've been placed, however you can build something new on that space, and it will destroy existing aspects.

You could probably use the Migrate ability from the Forest giant to move the strawberry bush somewhere else, although typically that ability is pretty far down on my list of abilities to unlock since it's not as useful as the other unlocks.

Answer (score 3):

Though you can't remove the aspects directly, you can overwrite any natural source by creating another natural source in the same spot.

In this case, you could simply make a new plant, upgrade it to a Strawberry, and then advance it with the Aspect you were wanting to use in the first place.